# how to make scriptable objects work with persistence data in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, persistence

My goal is to create 50 objects that all hold the same structure and is using persistence data.

I first learned about persistence data and followed Unity's official tutorial and got it to work. Since the tutorial is working with one object I started creating my game such as:

My methods to save and load the persistence data.

```
 public void saveBuy1()
    {


        Debug.Log("SavingBuy1");

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/buy1.dat");
        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();







        data.isBoxSold = 1;

        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
    }
```

```
public void loadBuy1()
    {
        Debug.Log("loading");



        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/buy1.dat"))

        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/buy1.dat", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();


            GameObject.Find("buyBox1").GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Item bought";
            isBoxsold1 = data.isBoxSold1;

        }
    }
```

My PlayerData class:

```
[Serializable]
class PlayerData {

public int coinsAmount;
public int isBoxsold;

}
```

Creating a box

```
 //Regular box 1
    int isBoxSold = 0;
    int price1 = 6;
    public Text boxPrice1;
    public Image boxImage1;
    public Button buyButton1;
```

But I quickly realised there must be a more efficient way to create my box objects than doing this:

```
 //Regular box 1
    int isBoxSold1 = 0;
    int price1 = 6;
    public Text boxPrice1;
    public Image boxImage1;
    public Button buyButton1;

//Regular box 2
    int isBoxSold2 = 0;
    int price2 = 6;
    public Text boxPrice2;
    public Image boxImage2;
    public Button buyButton2;
```

and then creating a duplicate of the loadBuy1 method and calling it loadBuy2 etc...

So I discovered scriptable objects which seems to fix the problem of having to create new attributes and fields for each box but instead creating one class once. However I can't grasp how one would connect these instances of box class using scriptable objects with persistence? Is there a way where I could create one load and save method to save and load all the persistence data for all the box objects at once? or would I still need to create a save and load method for each box?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is rather storing the data for each box in a proper `ScriptableObject` class.

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Box : ScriptableObject
{
    // Inspector
    [SerializeField] private int _isBoxSold = 0;
    [SerializeField] private int _price = 6;
    [SerializeField] private Text _boxPrice;
    [SerializeField] private Image _boxImage;
    [SerializeField] private Button _buyButton;

    // Public readonly properties
    public int IsBoxSold => _isBoxSold;
    public int Price => _price;
    public Text BoxPrice => _boxPrice;
}
```

and then store them as a List

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerData 
{
    public int coinsAmount;

    [SerializeField] private List<Box> _boxes;

    // Example: run through all boxes and update their texts
    public void UpdateBoxes()
    {
        foreach(var box in _boxes)
        {
            box.BoxPrice.text = box.Price.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

general note:

You should **never** use `+ "\"` for system paths! Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which automatically uses the correct path separators according to the target platform like e.g.

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "buy1.dat");
```

Comment: if I store them as a list and loop through would that mean I set the same price on all of the boxes? the boxes will need to have different values.

Comment: @Freddy no. As you can see in the example it uses the price of the according box `box.Price` and assigns it to this box's `box.BoxPrice.text`

Comment: first of all, thank you for the help. I understand now how you are using the foreach loop, however I been trying the last couple of hours to figure out how to insert a list of boxes in the editor. As I understand by making the class [Serializable] I should be able to see it in the editor and add my boxes? but I can't see it.. I even tried to create the playerdata with its own script and then adding the script, but it did not work.

Comment: @Freddy this depends. In your question you where talking about `ScriptableObject` .. do you need this? Because if not you could simply make the `Box` a normal class and make it `[Serializable]` otherwise you will only see references where you can drag a `ScriptableObject` in and your player will only Serialize these references. If using `ScriptableObject` you would also want to add a `[CreateAssetMenu]` tag to it so you can create new instances via the context menu in the `Assets`

Comment: The current script declares a Box type so you can declare and use the type for instances. To create instances, you can either do it by code or use right click in editor and find Box. This will create a new item in your project with a Unity logo as icon (the script has a C# icon). You can duplicate as many times you need and give different values to each of the instance. Then drag them anywhere you need to use them in code as shown in the PlayerData.

Comment: @derHugo I actually did use ```[CreateAssetMenu]```and have successfully created some boxes. But I still can't see the list: ```[SerializeField] private List<Box> _boxes;``` in the editor and therefor if I try to use the  ```UpdateBoxes()``` in my save persistence data method I get the error: ```NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.``` I think it must be because I never filled the list with any boxes..? once again thank you for taking your time to helping me out. Appreciate it!